# finding SSN using Oracle -sqldeveloper

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to write this query in Oracle -sqldeveloper, and I'm getting error message. this is my FIRST time working in Oracle, so please excuse me if I'm making a newbie mistakes.

I was ask to look at our db to see if end user by any chance enter their SSN number on this table. Some user might enter XXX-XX-1234, some might enter 123-34-567, some might enter XXXXXXXXX, some might enter 123456789 - I need to find ALL of them, I try this in SQL and it work but when i copy the code into oracle-sqldev it came back with error message and I try for a few days now to figure out what the heck is going on but I can't seen to figure it out.

here is there code i have in sql

```
select*
from ARTICLES 
where ARTICLE_BODY NOT LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

Comment: and what is the error message, and are you sure you are running the same query?  help us help you!

Comment: Hi -I just copy and past the error code and I realize I miss '  in the back, so not error, but its giving me everything on the "ARTICLE_BODY" even those that just have simple text. I'm sorry I didnt clarify the "ARTICLE_BODY" is just a text box.. that a user can enter random stuff

Comment: After the last comment, it's not clear if you still have an error or what's the problem you want to solve. Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Hi Alfabrove, no errors,  in the code pasted, I was trying to get only the SSN number or anything that is like an SSN but its giving me all data in the text box. I understand this is a bit unclear. what i want to get is only data that can be or is SSN.

Comment: Please clarify your specs.  You you want to return the ARTICLE_BODY where a match for one of the SSN formats is found, or do you want to return the SSN(s) themselves?

Comment: I'm trying to find SSN(s) themselves, anything that that have XXX-XX-XXXX OR XXX-XX-1234, OR XXXXXXXXX OR 123456789

Comment: Quite a precise search expression would be `[0-7]\d{2}-?\d{2}-?\d{4}`, since SSN's can't start with a digit higher than a 7.

Answer (score 0):

You should read the documentation about Like [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/conditions007.htm).  You can use [REGEXP_LIKE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm) but this can also be done with other Oracle built-ins

```
SELECT *
FROM ARTICLES
WHERE LENGTH(TRANSLATE(ARTICLE_BODY,
'1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ-','1234567890')) > 8
```

This will give you all the article bodies that have more than 8 numbers in their text.  You haven't given a lot of information about what can be entered and validating free text is hard but this should get you started.

However this will not work with CLOBS.

> Operations involving patterns as parameters, such as COMPARE, INSTR,
>   and SUBSTR do not support regular expressions or special matching
>   characters (such as % in the LIKE operator in SQL) in the pattern
>   parameter or substrings.
>   From the documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_lob.htm#i1015792)

In order to do this will have to create a PL/SQL procedure to read 4000 character chunks, put it into a VARCHAR2 variable and then search in that.

Comment: thank you for the link - I'm going to check it out now and hopefully understand the relation better. I will give the code a try.

Comment: I'm getting an error "ORA-22835: Buffer too small for CLOB to CHAR or BLOB to RAW conversion (actual: 4343, maximum: 4000)" I also try to do <9 to see if it return less, but same error message.

Comment: I just added select cast(substr(ARTICLE_BODY,1,2000) as varchar(4000 byte)) will see if this will work

Answer (score 0):

Here's a try with a number of different test strings. Definitely add more as you see fit.  Trying to select out of a block of text where the user can enter anything will never be 100%.  This attempts to select ARTICLE_BODY where it contains a string of at least 9 but not more than 11 characters consisting of one or more X's or one or more digits or one or one or two optional dashes while treating the string  multi-line and case insensitive (the where clause using REGEXP_LIKE). Then it surrounds the matches with triple square brackets to make the matches stand out in the output for you to verify.  Note that line 9 is selected as it meets the criteria even though it is not a SSN.  That will happen I'm afraid depending on what the user has entered.  Make sure the consumer of this data knows these results can't be verified to be 100% accurate.  Who knows what could be entered.  Just make sure the regular expression handles as many conditions as you know can be identified.  Good luck!

```
SQL> with articles(line, article_body) as (
   select 1, 'aaXXX-XX-1234aa' from dual union
   select 2, '123-45-6789'     from dual union
   select 3, '123456789'       from dual union
   select 4, 'XXXXXXXXX'       from dual union
   select 5, 'XXXXX.XXXX'      from dual union
   select 6, 'efs'             from dual union
   select 7, 'Some user might enter XXX-XX-1234, some might enter 123-34-567, some might enter XXXXXXXXX,
hem, I try this in SQL and it work but when i copy the code into oracle-sqldev it came back with error messa
he heck is going on but I cant seem to figure it out.' from dual union
   select 8, '123'             from dual union
   select 9, 'X12345678X'      from dual
   )
   select line, regexp_replace(article_body, '((X+|\d+|-{1,2}?){9,11})', '[[[\1]]]', 1, 0, 'im') Possible_ssns
   from articles
   where regexp_like(article_body, '(X+|\d+|-{1,2}?){9,11}', 'im')
   order by line;

      LINE POSSIBLE_SSNS
---------- --------------------------------------------------
         1 aa[[[XXX-XX-1234]]]aa
         2 [[[123-45-6789]]]
         3 [[[123456789]]]
         4 [[[XXXXXXXXX]]]
         7 Some user might enter [[[XXX-XX-1234]]], some migh
           t enter [[[123-34-567]]], some might enter [[[XXXX
           XXXXX]]], some might enter [[[123456789]]] - I nee
           d to find ALL of them, I try this in SQL and it wo
           rk but when i copy the code into oracle-sqldev it
           came back with error message and I try for a few d
           ays now to figure out what the heck is going on bu
           t I cant seem to figure it out.
         9 [[[X12345678X]]]

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: thank you, will give this a try as well... I already mention that it's nearly impossible to find SSN in an open text box, and whatever I might be able to find, might not even be SSN or that it might not cover 100%, but I was told to find anything or as much as I can... but there's over 7k records.